# How to modify input wires before sending them as input in another modules?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I want to design a 8 bit adder-subtracter in verilog. when ***cin*** is 1, it should add 2 numbers, when 0, it should subtracts.

For performing subtraction, I said to ***add number1 and ~number2 and 1***. here is the code:(when subtracting, ***cin = 0***. so ***~cin = 1***. and it the 3 values will be added by a full_adder which works truly) this is done for all 8 bits.

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps
module full_adder(input a, b, cin, clock, output reg sum, cout);
    always @(negedge clock) begin
        sum = #7 a ^ b ^ cin;
        cout = #7 (a & b) | (a & cin) | (b & cin);
    end
endmodule


module adder_subtracter_8bit
    (input [7:0] num1, num2, input cin, clock, output [7:0] result, output cout);
    //1 is for adding, 0 for subtracting

    wire w0, w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6;

    assign #3 num2[0] = (num2[0] ~^ cin);
    full_adder ADD0 (.a(num1[0]), .b(num2[0]), .cin(~cin), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[0]), .cout(w0));

    assign #3 num2[1] = (num2[1] ~^ w0);
    full_adder ADD1 (.a(num1[1]), .b(num2[1]), .cin(w0), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[1]), .cout(w1));

    assign #3 num2[2] = (num2[2] ~^ w1);
    full_adder ADD2 (.a(num1[2]), .b(num2[2]), .cin(w1), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[2]), .cout(w2));

    assign #3 num2[3] = (num2[3] ~^ w2);
    full_adder ADD3 (.a(num1[3]), .b(num2[3]), .cin(w2), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[3]), .cout(w3));

    assign #3 num2[4] = (num2[4] ~^ w3);
    full_adder ADD4 (.a(num1[4]), .b(num2[4]), .cin(w3), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[4]), .cout(w4));

    assign #3 num2[5] = (num2[5] ~^ w4);
    full_adder ADD5 (.a(num1[5]), .b(num2[5]), .cin(w4), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[5]), .cout(w5));

    assign #3 num2[6] = (num2[6] ~^ w5);
    full_adder ADD6 (.a(num1[6]), .b(num2[6]), .cin(w5), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[6]), .cout(w6));

    assign #3 num2[7] = (num2[7] ~^ w6);
    full_adder ADD7 (.a(num1[7]), .b(num2[7]), .cin(w6), .clock(clock)
                         , .sum(result[7]), .cout(cout));

endmodule
```

however, this isn't work properly and the outputs(which are wires showing the result) are all X.
[image: Signals]

**testbench:**

```
`timescale 1ns/100ps

module TEST_adder_subtracter_8bit();
    reg [7:0] a, b;
    reg clock, cin;
    wire [7:0] result;
    wire cout;

    adder_subtracter_8bit UUT(.num1(a), .num2(b), .cin(cin), .clock(clock),
                          .result(result), .cout(cout));

    initial repeat (2000) #7 clock = ~clock;

    initial begin
        a = 8'b0000_0000;
        b = 8'b0000_0000;
        clock = 0;
        cin = 1;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0000_0001;
        b = 8'b0000_0001;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0000_0111;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0000_0001;
        b = 8'b0000_0111;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0001_1010;
        b = 8'b0001_0011;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0000_0001;
        b = 8'b1111_1111;

        #180;
        a = 8'b1111_1111;
        b = 8'b0000_0001;

        #180;
        a = 8'b1111_0000;
        b = 8'b1111_0110;

        #180;
        a = 8'b0111_0011;
        b = 8'b0111_0111;

        #180;
        a = 8'b1111_1111;
        b = 8'b1111_1111;

    end

endmodule
```

Can anyone say how should I fix it?

Comment: You should provide more of your code and the test bench. Looks like your Cin is unknown (undefined).

Comment: @Nazar I entered the whole code

Comment: Also I advice to change your name. cin is often a carry-in. If it controls add/subtract it should be called something like that.

Comment: Double post: You also posted this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068571/how-to-modify-input-wires-before-sending-them-as-input-in-another-modules?s=1|0.0000

Comment: @oldfart i deleted it on stackoverflow

Comment: Post your test bench code. Do you provide `cin` value to your `adder_subtracter_8bit`?

Comment: @Nazar testbench added

Comment: Based on your timing diagram, the `cin` is unknown, so you would expect the outputs to be unknown too. Try changing the `cin = 1` to `cin = 1'b1`in your test bench

Comment: @Nazar i tried it as you said. but it didn't work!

Comment: @toolic you mean I should create another module for inverting the bits?? what should I write isntead of num2[0] = (num2[0] ~^ cin) ???

Answer (score 2):

what I feel as the mistake in your code is `assign #3 num2[0] = (num2[0] ~^ cin)` and other similar expressions. Try changing the name of the net 'num2[0]' on the left-hand side. It will then work. Further, there is a mistake in your code for the expression series that involves 'num2'. All such expressions should be `assign #3 NUM2[i] = (num2[i] ~^ cin), i = 1,...,7`. You may find my version of the Verilog code for the problem below.

Verilog Code:

```
`timescale 1 ns / 100 ps
module FullAdder (
input a, b, cin, Clk,
output reg s, cout
);
    always @(negedge Clk)
    begin
        s = #7 a ^ b ^ cin;
        cout = #7 (a & b) | (b & cin) | (cin & a);
    end
endmodule

module AddSubtract (
    input [7:0] a, b,
    input Cin, Clk,
    output [7:0] sum,
    output Cout
);
    genvar i;
    wire [8:0] C;
    wire [7:0] B;
    assign C[0] = ~Cin;
    generate
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i + 1)
        begin   : AddSubArray
            assign #3 B[i] = b[i] ~^ Cin;
            FullAdder FA (.a(a[i]), .b(B[i]), .cin(C[i]), .Clk(Clk), .s(sum[i]), .cout(C[i + 1]));
        end
    endgenerate
    assign Cout = C[8];
endmodule
```

Comment: It may be worth clarifying that HDL are continuously evaluated (event triggered) rather than sequential like a lot of programming languages.